Python requests.session object termination, within the context of an API?
I've got a flask application, few endpoints, my API just scrapes one site, uses Beautiful Soup with lxml to parse data into JSON objects and returns it.
The target site needs authentication, and persistent cookies to actually get the data. That's why I use a requests.session object, for each user.
I don't quite get how this would eventually not lead to cluttering the memory with lone requests.session objects floating about. Any solution? Or is it a non-problem.
Reading through the docs tells me requests.session objects don't close themselves, neither do they provide a time based parameter to do it for them.
It seems .close method is the only way. Which feels awkward to use within an api.

@AndrewYim Yes I am currently using context managers, but that's part of the issue. What I had hoped for, initially, was for one user to log in, then I create a session object, dedicated to processing any other requests come from that user.
